# React web component not loading in angular application - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'adoptedCallback' in undefined

Tags: reactjs, angular, web-component

I have simple web component in react

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import reactToWebComponent from 'react-to-webcomponent';


function Test() {
  return (
    <h1> Hello </h1>
  )
}

const webcomponent = reactToWebComponent(Test, React, ReactDOM );
customElements.define("hello-react", webcomponent);
```

I m building this react app and serving on some port
The application work on standalone mode with http-server.

But angular application When I'm trying to access this web component.

Getting this below error while loading in angular

```
react-to-webcomponent.es.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'adoptedCallback' in undefined
at Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (react-to-webcomponent.es.js:44)
at Proxy.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
at zone-evergreen.js:2171
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CustomElementRegistry.target.<computed> [as define] (zone-evergreen.js:2168)
at index.js:8
at index.js:8
at index.js:8
```

Comment: create class and extends `reactToWebComponent` and use that class to create web component.

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper class and extends `reactToWebComponent` and use that class to create web component. Looks like this issue is something related to angular change detection or custom element hook lifecycle events.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import reactToWebComponent from 'react-to-webcomponent';


export class MyReactWebComponent extends reactToWebComponent {

}

export function Test() {
  return (
    <h1> Hello </h1>
  )
}

const webcomponent = new MyReactWebComponent(Test, React, ReactDOM );
customElements.define("hello-react", webcomponent);
```